# REF error when setting cell formula Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a custom function called `=matchlist` using apps script. That function is working with no problem. I also created another function called `refreshTBA` which clears the content of a certain cell (`A2`) and replaces it with the formula `=matchlist(Setup!$b$2)`​. When I run this function while I have the sheet open, there is no problem. However, any time I navigate away from the page and open it back up, the function in the cell is `=matchlist(#REF)`.

Here is the code for the refreshTBA function:

```
function refreshTBA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MatchImport")
  var cell = ss.getRange("A2")
  cell.clearContent()
  cell.setFormula('=matchlist(Setup!$b$2)')
  var cell = ss.getRange("A300")
  cell.clearContent()
  cell.setValue('Refreshed') 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this thanks to help on the Google Product Forum.

When putting a formula using the `setFormula` paramter, there is no need to include the equal sign. If I use `setValue` then I should